# MV3 declarativeNetRequest Block not replacing webRequest properly

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have a very simple webRequest blocking operation that works perfectly on MV3 but by migrating to MV3 declarativeNetRequestit doesn't work

What is the equivalent of the  webRequest  on the declarativeNetRequest for this simple operation:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(){ return {cancel: true}; },
  {
    urls: ["*://*.example.com/mwlite/service-worker.js", "*://*.example.com/mwlite/manifest.json"]
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

On MV3 I have:

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules(
    {addRules:[{
        "id": id,
        "priority": 1,
        "action": {     "type": "block"
        },
        "condition": {"urlFilter": "*://*.example.com/mwlite/service-worker.js", "resourceTypes": ["image",
        "media",
        "main_frame",
        "sub_frame",
        "stylesheet",
        "script",
        "font",
        "xmlhttprequest",
        "ping",
        "websocket",
        "other"], "tabIds" : tabMultiId }}    
        ],
        removeRuleIds: [id]
    },
);
```

I have tried this and it simply doesn't work!
Greetings and thank you very much for anyone that try to help.

Comment: You may have leftovers of the old rules while you were testing previous code so try removing them using getSessionRules/getDynamicRules + updateSessionRules/updateDynamicRules. Also note that Chrome doesn't unregister the currently registered service worker of the site. You can do it manually using chrome.browsingData API.

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm you are right it worked. Can you please take a look to this other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74391398/mv3-declarativenetrequest-and-x-frame-options-deny

Answer (score 1):

Please check your configuration as it works correctly with the following configuration.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

myscript.js

```
const id = 1;

chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules(
  {
    addRules: [{
      "id": id,
      "priority": 1,
      "action": {
        "type": "block"
      },
      "condition": {
        "urlFilter": "*://*.yahoo.co.jp", "resourceTypes": ["image",
          "media",
          "main_frame",
          "sub_frame",
          "stylesheet",
          "script",
          "font",
          "xmlhttprequest",
          "ping",
          "websocket",
          "other"]
      }
    }
    ],
    removeRuleIds: [id]
  },
);
```

Comment: Hi @Norio Yamamoto you example is right. It works. But my adventure with declarativeNetRequest. It is not working is this other case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74391398/mv3-declarativenetrequest-and-x-frame-options-deny